# Prestashop search from pages and categories with product search

Tags: php, prestashop

I am using prestashop. I have already search functionality.
But that works with products such a way that I want to make search that searches 
keywords from pages and categories also.

I have the script from SearchController.php that is currently running. have any idea ?

```
<?php

if (($query = Tools::getValue('search_query', Tools::getValue('ref'))) && !is_array($query))

          {

            $this->productSort();
            $this->n = abs((int)(Tools::getValue('n', Configuration::get('PS_PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE'))));
            $this->p = abs((int)(Tools::getValue('p', 1)));
            $search = Search::find($this->context->language->id, $query, $this->p, $this->n, $this->orderBy, $this->orderWay);
            Hook::exec('actionSearch', array('expr' => $query, 'total' => $search['total']));
            $nbProducts = $search['total'];
            $this->pagination($nbProducts);
            $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
                'products' => $search['result'], // DEPRECATED (since to 1.4), not use this: conflict with block_cart module
                'search_products' => $search['result'],
                'nbProducts' => $search['total'],
                'search_query' => $query,
                'homeSize' => Image::getSize('home_default')));
        }
?>
```

Comment: You should really go for a custome module with this "problem". But if you don't feel like it then you should start with classes/search.php instead and locate a public static function called find()

Comment: Can you please tell us what was the idea behind including categies also in search results. Thanks in advance.